# Can I make nautilus show book covers as thumbnails for Epub files?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, thumbnails, ebooks, nautilus-script

#### **The Problem**

Can I make nautilus show thumbnails of book covers for files in  `.epub` format?

It shows thumbnails for pdf files but not [`.epub`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB). Is this achievable by adding a thumbnailer?

Each of these `.epub` files has a `cover.jpeg` file inside it.

[image: Screenshot]

[Example Epub file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B624A6HYSHmUS0FHNTlZNldGRW8) (Google Drive)

Comment: Sure, but where to get the images from? Ah, wait, it is inside the files.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Each of the epub files has a `cover.jpeg`  file just inside it

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked it :) Could you add a link to an epub file? I don't have any to check on.

Comment: @JacobVlijm let me upload it

Comment: Got it! not sure if I can try today, but I definitely will :)

Comment: Hi Sumeet I am so sorry for the delay, kind of in a time shortage, I can only spend a few minutes per day atm. Will get back though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've updated the question with a development this might be helpful

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh make that an answer please (you can use the answer as a work in progress)

Comment: @Rinzwind but that answer doesn't work?  How will I let people know that I want to find out what's wrong with the posted answer? (i'm still pretty new here)

Comment: A better approach would be to edit your question and include the "update" as though you had written it this way from the beginning. As it stands, it really isn't very clear which is why @Rinzwind suggested you post an answer: presumably, he thought the script did work at least partially. So, just rewrite this so that i) you state the problem and ii) the solution you have so far and iii) exactly what more you need. How does it work and how does it fail?

Comment: @terdon let me edit the question according to your approach

Comment: @terdon Is the updated version Good enough? more suggestions are welcome ;)

Comment: There's no need to re-invent the wheel here. This has been done. See [here](https://github.com/marianosimone/epub-thumbnailer)

Comment: @ElderGeek I think I'm using that same script, but from another answer, I think I should *ReadMe* on Github

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Bravo for adding the link to your question. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to worry about scripts. do everything one by one

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pil
```

Now [download this](https://github.com/marianosimone/epub-thumbnailer/archive/master.zip) file from [epub-thumbnailer GitHub page](https://github.com/marianosimone/epub-thumbnailer)

now extract that file to a folder, and go into the extracted folder, Right click in empty space and select <kbd>Open in Terminal</kbd> and type the following command

```
sudo python install.py install
nautilus -q
```

now check your Epub files they should have thumbnails

Comment: well I already did it with the help of  [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek) in comments but thanks for the answer anyway. procedure was pretty much the same

Comment: Thx. Got it working on ubuntu 18 by installing: sudo apt-get install python-pil

Answer (score 3):

It works like a charm in Ubuntu 22.04.01

```bash
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ python --version
Python 3.10.4
```

### Step by step instructions

1. Clone the epub-thumbnailer project`git clone https://github.com/marianosimone/epub-thumbnailer.git`
2. Change directory `cd epub-thumbnailer/`
3. Install Pillow `pip install Pillow`
4. Install epub-thumbnailer `sudo python3 install.py install`

```bash
Checking dependencies ...

Required dependencies:
    Python Imaging Library .......
OK

Installing epub-thumbnailer to /usr/bin/ ...
OK
Installing thumbnailer hook in /usr/share/thumbnailers ...
OK
You might have to restart your file manager for the thumbnailer to be activated.
```

5. Clear the cache `rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails`
6. Restart your file manager
7. Done!